# How does this allow us to use crypto function for hashing?

Tags: c#, encryption

I saw this piece of code in
[github](https://gist.github.com/hitbtc-com/9808530)

```
public static string CalculateSignature(string text, string secretKey)
{
    using (var hmacsha512 = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey)))
    {
        hmacsha512.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
        return string.Concat(hmacsha512.Hash.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")).ToArray()); // minimalistic hex-encoding and lower case
    }
}
```

What does this code do?

```
string.Concat(hmacsha512.Hash.Select(b => b.ToString("x2"))
```

As far as I know you can't pass a String to `tostring()` method.

Why you need select?

Can the code be simplified? Why do `toarray()` and then `concat` again?

In particular I have no idea what does `b.ToString("x2")` did. I am surprised it even compiles. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx says that tostring method doesn't take argument.

Then why the hell do I need that select thingy. What is the coder trying to accomplish.

So we got a bunch of bytes array and then we got to use computeHash to get a bunch of bytes array. And then we reencode to string. That's the basic idea.

So why does turning texts into bytes are pretty much quick `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)` and yet we got to do strange things to turn those text into some string

Comment: `byte.ToString("x2")` produces a hexadecimal representation of said byte. If you're unsure about what an expression is or the types involved, Visual Studio is usually quite accommodating when you hover over things. Yes, this can be simplified -- `BitConverter.ToString(byte[]).Replace("-", "")` is shorter, although not necessarily more efficient (and if you want lowercase, you need an extra `ToLower`).

Comment: regarding the `.ToArray` `Concat` mixture - [`String.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991828(v=vs.110).aspx) for `IEnumerable` was added in .NET4.0 so presumably this code is either older than that or is meant to be backwards compatible to older .NET versions

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y11056e9(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

> In particular I have no idea what does b.ToString("x2") did. I am surprised it even complies

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y11056e9(v=vs.110).aspx and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings. It formats a byte as a two character lowercase hexadecimal string.  0x03 => "03", 0x0A => "0a".

> Why you need select?

`Select` transforms one enumerable to another.  Since Hash is a `byte[]` it's `IEnumerable<byte>`, so this turns each `byte` into the value from the evaluation of the expression within.  Thus each byte becomes the two character hex string.

> Why do toarray() and then concat again?

`String.Concat(string[])` was added in .NET Framework 1.0/1.1.  `String.Concat(IEnumerable<string>)` was added in .NET Framework 4.0.  If this code was written against .NET 3.5 it was "as optimal" as it could be (without writing it in via the more efficient `StringBuilder` approach).

> What is the coder trying to accomplish.

Did you run it?  It produces a hexadecimal string representing the HMAC-SHA-2-512 of the data under the secret key.

> I am surprised it even complies

It is only using syntax from C# 3.0 (the newest thing it uses is [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions).  C# 3.0 turns 10 years old next month.  (It was released with .NET Framework 3.5)

> Can the code be simplified?

Sure.

```
public static string CalculateSignature(string text, string secretKey)
{
    using (var hmacsha512 = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey)))
    {
        byte[] hmac = hmacsha512.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(hmac.Length * 2);

        foreach (byte b in hmac)
        {
            builder.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Well, that's more performant.  Maybe it's not "simpler", depends on your definitions thereof.

Comment: In vb.net tostring does not take a string argument. So I wonder why I can do tostring("x2")

Comment: @J.Chang: `Byte.ToString(String)` is a BCL method available to any .NET language. I'm not a regular VB.NET programmer, but my Visual Studio shows this overload. (I know there's a dubious feature to "hide advanced members", but I don't think `ToString(String)` counts as one, and in either case hiding it doesn't mean it's unavailable.)

Comment: Yea well it's not on their web.

Comment: The one bartonjs build is much more clear. Basically for every byte just put a d digit string. It makes perfect sense.

Comment: I don't know what "it's not on their web" means, but if you mean Microsoft's own documentation, [here you go](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/y11056e9?cs-lang=vb).